# Boost.Asio concurrency problems on threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, boost

i'm trying to make this program that has a few features:

-Networking with Boost.Asio (yeah, i got most of it figured out).

-Multi-threading with Boost.Thread and Boost.Asio.

The important aspects of the program are a few threads, one that will constantly try to read and one that will check the contents of an std::vector and write them to a textbox (i'm using Nana C++ for the GUI) and on the socket.
So i know that i need to use atomics in some points, because i also need these threads to be able to close themselves (using a bool maybe?) and be able to read and write in the vector. But this is proving very difficult.

What i really want to know is:
How can i have these threads doing the write and read operations and accessing the vector without damaging the data or causing undefined behavior?
And how can i "kill" the threads without doing any harm?

I do know that this is very confuse, so the following is the code i've built so far:

```
short port;
wstring password;
atomic<bool> stop = false;
vector<wstring> msgQueue;
atomic<vector<wstring>> sLog;
boost::asio::io_service io_service;

class session
{
public:
    session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
        : socket_(io_service)
    {
    }

    tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return socket_;
    }

    void start()
    {
        thread(read);
        while (!stop)
        {
            if (!msgQueue.empty())
            {
                std::string sending = ws2s(msgQueue.front());
                msgQueue.erase(msgQueue.begin());
                socket_.write_some(boost::asio::buffer(sending.c_str(), sending.length()));
            }
        }
    }

    void read()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            socket_.read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length));
        }
    }

    void handle_read(const boost::system::error_code& error,
        size_t bytes_transferred)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            //boost::asio::async_write(socket_,
                //boost::asio::buffer(data_, bytes_transferred),
                //);
        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

    void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            socket_.async_read_some(boost::asio::buffer(data_, max_length),
                boost::bind(&session::handle_read, this,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
        }
        else
        {
            delete this;
        }
    }

private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    enum { max_length = 1024 };
    char data_[max_length];
};

class server
{
public:
    server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
        : io_service_(io_service),
        acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
    {
        session* new_session = new session(io_service_);
        acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
            boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }

    void handle_accept(session* new_session,
        const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            new_session->start();
            new_session = new session(io_service_);
            acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
                boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error));
        }
        else
        {
            delete new_session;
        }
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

    void praca()
    {
        try
        {
            server s(io_service, port);
            sLog; // push_back() here?
            io_service.run();
        }
        catch (std::exception& e)
        {
            std::string raps(const_cast<char*>(e.what()));
            MsgBox(L"Error", s2ws(raps));
        }
    }

    void start()
    {
        stop = false;
        thread(praca);
        append(L"Server is now running. Waiting for client connection...", false);
    }
```

I do know this code has major flaws and that it would certainly cause a lot of exceptions if it compiled.

I also forgot to mention, i wanted to use a password while sending/receiving or just on connection time, but i think i can figure that out once the current mess is solved.

Any suggestions on how can i do this, or if i should use something else instead of what i've been trying so far (the methods or the libraries)?

Btw, i'm using Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 8.1.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are set on using the one `std::vector` for your data, you will need to use a `boost::mutex` (or similar) to ensure the reading and writing threads do not access the data at the same time. I recommend reading the [boost documentation on synchronization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.tutorial.internal_locking.concurrent_threads_of_execution) which I guarantee will answer your questions about how to ensure you don't have two threads accessing the data at once.

Another option is as you find data you wish to write, immediately tell your Writer class/thread about it. I've provided an example of what this looks like

```
class Writer
{
public:
    Writer() : io_service(), writerThread(&Writer::WriterThread, this), threadRunning(true) {}

    ~Writer()
    {
        // tell the thread to stop
        threadRunning = false;
        // wait for the thread to stop
        writerThread.join();
    }

    void AddDataToWrite(const std::string& sData) { io_service.post(boost::bind(&std::vector<std::string>::push_back, boost::ref(dataToWrite), sData)); }

private:
    void WriterThread()
    {
        // while the thread is running, process logic:
        while (threadRunning)
        {
            // Check for new work:
            io_service.run();
            // Prepare for new work:
            io_service.reset();

            // Process any work:
            std::vector<std::string>::iterator it = dataToWrite.begin();
            while (it != dataToWrite.end())
            {
                // Write the data:
                std::cout << *it << std::endl;
                // Remove the data:
                it = dataToWrite.erase(it);
            }
        }
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    boost::thread writerThread;
    bool threadRunning; // NB: make this atomic!
    std::vector<std::string> dataToWrite;

};

int main()
{
    Writer w;
    for ( int i = 0;; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 10000 == 0)
        {
            w.AddDataToWrite("Hello");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The `Writer` class will create a thread and process all its work there. When `Writer::AddDataToWrite` is called, the `boost::asio::io_service` will post the work to the thread (`WriterThread`) to handle. The example here shows two threads: the main thread (the contents of `main()`) and the writer thread ( the contents of `Writer::WriterThread`).

This example also answers your second question about how to ensure a thread is closed without doing harm. A `bool` is used: when the thread is created, `threadRunning` is set to `true`. The thread uses this `bool` and checks if its `true` before running. In the destructor of `Writer`, the `bool` is set to `false`. This means the thread will stop processing the data and the function will terminate and the thread will finish. The call to `join()` waits for that to occur (so if the thread needed to run for several more seconds, your application would wait until it had finished). This is important because your thread might be using resources that would get deallocated once the destructor (or other destructors) had been called.

It's important to note that `threadRunning` should be `atomic`. This is because the `bool` is used in two threads: the `bool` is read on the writer thread fairly constantly, but the `Writer` destructor will be called on the main thread (where the `bool` will be set to `false`).

Comment: Changing the basic thread for a class that procecess the work on io_service and receives it through a method. That's a fantastic solution, particulartly, i think it's better than considering a mutex solution, because my code was already very unorganized before. Thanks.

Comment: On a side-note, i would like to remind you that since the release of C++0x, std::vector<T>::push_back is an overloaded function, so to use it on the sample code we should have: `io_service.post(boost::bind(static_cast<void (std::vector<string>::*)(const string&)>
   (&std::vector<string>::push_back),
   boost::ref(dataToWrite), sData));`